# Why isn't my user control paint event filling my rectangle only on one control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
For one of the two controls I create (the first one) it works. But for the second one, it doesn't?
I've tried many things to fix this but I haven't come any closer to a solution any ideas?

[What happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Ppv.png)

Code where they are created:

```
    public MessageLogView()
    {
        MessageBubble bubble = new MessageBubble("Hey there Steve I love you", DateTime.Today, Color.FromArgb(255,255,255), new Padding(10, 10, 10, 10));

        bubble.Location = new Point(5, 5);

        this.Controls.Add(bubble);

        MessageBubble bubble2 = new MessageBubble("K, good for you", DateTime.Today, Color.FromArgb(220, 248, 198), new Padding(10, 10, 10, 10));

        bubble2.Location = new Point(5, 5 + bubble.BubbleHeight + 5);

        this.Controls.Add(bubble2);

    }
```

The usercontrol:

```
 public partial class MessageBubble : UserControl
{
    private string Text;
    private DateTime Date;
    private Color BubbleColor = Color.FromArgb(220, 248, 198);
    private Size stringSize, datestringSize;
    public Font textFont { get; set; } = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
    public Font dateFont { get; set; } = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
    public Color textColor { get; set; } = Color.Black;
    public Color dateColor { get; set; } = Color.FromArgb(180, 208, 158);
    public int cornerRadius { get; set; } = 5;

    public int BubbleHeight { get
        {
            return this.Padding.Top + this.Padding.Bottom + stringSize.Height + 5 + datestringSize.Height;
        }
    }
    public int BubbleWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Padding.Left + this.Padding.Right + stringSize.Width;
        }
    }

    public MessageBubble(string text, DateTime date, Color color, Padding padding)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Text = text;
        this.BubbleColor = color;
        Date = date;
        stringSize = this.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(Text, this.textFont).ToSize();
        datestringSize = this.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(Date.ToString("hh:mm tt"), this.dateFont).ToSize();
        this.Padding = padding;
        this.Width = this.BubbleWidth;
        this.Height = this.BubbleHeight;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BubbleColor), Bounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.textFont, new SolidBrush(this.textColor), new Point(this.Padding.Left,this.Padding.Top));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Date.ToString("hh:mm tt"), this.dateFont, new SolidBrush(this.dateColor), new Point(this.Width - datestringSize.Width - Padding.Right, this.Padding.Top + stringSize.Height + 5));
        Console.WriteLine($"Drawn: {this.Text} - {this.Bounds.X}, {this.Bounds.Y} - {this.BubbleWidth}, {this.BubbleHeight}/{this.Bounds.Width}, {this.Bounds.Height} - {this.BubbleColor.ToString() }");
    }
}
```

Comment: @mjwills I expected it to draw the second one with the specified background colour Color.FromArgb(220, 248, 198). But instead it comes out transparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strange behavior is because of using [`Bounds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds.aspx) instead of [`ClientRectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle.aspx). They are different:

- `Bounds`: Size and location of the control **relative to the parent control**.
- `ClientRectangle`: The rectangle that represents the client area of the control.

Use `ClientRectangle` when filling rectangle.

When you put a control having `(100, 100)` as its size on the point `(10,10)` on the parent, client rectangle will be `(0, 0, 100, 100)` and `Bounds` will be `(10, 10, 100, 100)`.

**Note:** You need to dispose the GDI+ objects, otherwise you will be faced with *GDI leak* soon. Create and use them in a using:

```
using (var brush = new SolidBrush(this.BubbleColor))
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, ClientRectangle);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `Usercontrol`'s `BackColor` to the `BubbleColor` in the constructor.

```
BubbleColor = color;
```

Now it looks as expected:

[image]

**But** the actual error comes from the `Bounds` property. It is the rectangle the control is contained in and **its location is the controls's location**, so, depending on the numbers, you are drawing mostly outside of the bubble.

Instead you could use:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, Bounds.Size);
```

But the most natural solution is to use the **right property**, which is `ClientRectangle`..

And, as Reza's cross-post says: Do make sure to dispose you GDI+ resources, namely the Brushes..

Comment: out of curiosity, I see it in the constructor. As the first bubble got it's color, but the second one.