# copy only the picturebox1 area to picturebox2 from the form1 with c# and AForge

Tags: c#, aforge

In my code it is copying from left corner of my screen to picturebox2.
I want only picturebox1 content to show at picturebox2.
Library used here is AForge.

```
    private void FinalFrame_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        System.Drawing.Image img = pictureBox1.Image;

        var bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Bounds.Width,
                            pictureBox1.Bounds.Height,
                            PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(this.pictureBox1.Bounds.X,
                                    this.pictureBox1.Bounds.Y,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    this.pictureBox1.Bounds.Size,
                                    CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        BitmapData srcData = bm.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height),
        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
        PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        UnmanagedImage unmanagedImg = new UnmanagedImage(srcData);
        //Gray Image
        UnmanagedImage grayImage = UnmanagedImage.Create(bm.Width, bm.Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
        Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709.Apply(unmanagedImg, grayImage);
        pictureBox2.Image = grayImage.ToManagedImage();
    }
```

Comment: this.pictureBox1.Bounds.X Look at the value. It is not what you expect. pbox.pictureBox1.Left etc may help. But:You need screen coordinates. Look into ScreentoPoint(Control) and Control.PointToScreen. Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51001476/why-isnt-my-user-control-paint-event-filling-my-rectangle-only-on-one-control/51001774?s=1|0.0000#51001774)

Comment: Can you please redefine the code?